# Passing Partial Lists into Python Function

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python program to read in a text file and pull out some information.  There are three items I'm trying to find, one real number, and two lists.   The script stores the lines of the text file as a list `inLines`.  When reading through the lines the script uses `for curLine in inLines:` and then searches all of the lines for a specific key.  Once I find the search key I would like to pass the remaining portion of `inLines` into a function, read thorugh a few more lines, and then return to the main script at the line where the function left off.

Here's a little diagram of what I want to happen (code instructions given as comments)

```
line of text that doesn't matter    #Read by main, nothing interesting happens
line of text that doesn't matter    #Read by main, nothing interesting happens
search key A                        #Read by main, all following lines passed to function A
line that matters                   #Read by function A, stores in object
line that matters                   #Read by function A, stores in object

line that matters                   #Read by function A, stores in object


search key B                        #Read by function A, return to main, all following lines passed to function B


line that matters                   #Read by function B, stores in object

search key C                        #Read by function B, return to main, all following lines passed to function C
line that matters                   #Red by function C, stores in object
```

So each search key tells the program which function to be in (and the different keys could be in any order).  When the script finds the key, it passes all further lines to the correct function, and whenever a function finds a search key, it breaks, and passes all further lines back to main (which then pass the same lines to the appropriate function)

Sorry for the book of a question, and I'm just learning Python after years of FORTRAN, so if anyone can think of a better way to go about this, I'm open to suggestions.  Thanks in advance

Comment: You can pass a file handle to a function and continue `for l in inf` within that function (though I'm not able to write a full answer right now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little script is *close* to what you want.  It discards the lines that occur prior to a search function being specified.  You ought to be able to adapt it to your needs.

```
import sys


def search_func_a(l):
    """
    Called for things that follow `search key A`
    """
    print 'A: %s' % l


def search_func_b(l):
    """
    Called for things that follow `search key B`
    """
    print 'B: %s' % l


def search_key_func(l):
    """
    Returns the associated "search function" for each search string.
    """
    if 'search key A' in l:
        return search_func_a
    if 'search key B' in l:
        return search_func_b
    return None


def main():
    # Start with a default handler.  This changes as `search key` lines are
    # found.
    handler = lambda _: 0 

    for line in open('test.txt'):
        # search_key_func returns None for non `search key` lines.  In that
        # case, continue to use the last `search function` found.
        search_func = search_key_func(line) 
        if search_func:
            # If a search line is found, don't pass it into the search func.
            handler = search_func
            continue
        handler(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: I'm a little new to Python, so some of what you're doing is completely new to me, but it looks like something I want to do.  But what is this handler thing doing?

Comment: handler is the function that `handles` the current line type being processed.  This is set according to the current line being read.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem with doing something like this?

```
inA = inB = inC = False
for line in file:
  if keyA(line):
    inA = True
    inB = inC = False
  elif keyB(line):
    inB = True
    inA = inC = False
  elif keyC(line):
    inC = True
    inA = inB = False
  if inA:
    processA(line)
  if inB:
    processB(line)
  if inC:
    processC(line)
```

Are you asking if there's some faster method?

Comment: Well, I'm already iterating through the lines of the file, so I don't know if I can have a loop within a loop where they are both iterating the same list

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8

import sys

def find(haystack, needle, start_line = 0):
    for i, line in enumerate(haystack[start_line:]):
        if line == needle:
            return i + 1
    raise("%s not found." % needle)

def main(argv = None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv

    with open(argv[1], 'r') as f:
        text = f.read().splittext()

    find(text, "c", find(text, "b", find(text, "a")))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

I'm not sure what you mean "store in object", but the code is easily modifiable to suit your purposes.